# Sitecore Commerce Connect Module License Missing on Fresh Install

Tags: installation, sitecore-commerce

I've just installed a fresh `Sitecore 8.1 Update-2` instance on my dev machine for a client and I'm getting the following warning on the Home item:

**Required license is missing.**

```
You require one of the following licenses to use the Sitecore Commerce Connect module. 'Sitecore.Commerce.Connect' or 'Sitecore.Commerce.ConnectPartner'
```

I'm using the client's license for this install and we are not using the Sitecore Commerce Connect module on their site. Why is this message popping up and how do I suppress it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not have keys for the `Sitecore.Commerce.Connect` or `Sitecore.Commerce.ConnectPartner` modules in your license file, the following message may be displayed above the `Quick Info` section when opening the Content Editor:

```
You require one of the following licenses to use the Sitecore Commerce Connect module.
`Sitecore.Commerce.Connect` or `Sitecore.Commerce.ConnectPartner`
These license keys are not included by default.
```

**Solution**

To fix the issue, put the [Sitecore.Support.105037.config](https://kb.sitecore.net/~/media/597E7A6CF7194F518F5E25145748B9D1.ashx?la=en) file into the \App_Config\Include folder.

https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/852031

Comment: Not that I find your answer invalid, but I don't understand why Sitecore would put a support config to remove this warning, when clearly the issue is the configs just don't need to be enabled, if you aren't using Sitecore.Commerce.

Comment: @PeteNavarra this solution was recommended by Sitecore support.

Comment: Do you ever question Sitecore Support? Not saying that in a negative way. But clearly, Sitecore's product enablement strategy has been to enable/disable configurations. So why provide a patch removal for a specific processor? Is it that your ticket to Sitecore was specific in the sense of "Oh hey, we want to use this product, but don't have a key and are getting this error, what do we do?" I could see them providing a patch config.  But that's different from just not wanting to use the product at all, and the configs being enabled by default. Obviously, i'd love to be wrong here. =)

Comment: First answer from sitecore support was: we don't resolve license issues, we resolve technical issues

Answer (score 6):

There are 2 configs that start with `Sitecore.Commerce.xxxx` in the `\App_Config\Include folder` out of the box. If you aren't using the Commerce components, these can be safely disabled.

The file names are:

1. Sitecore.Commerce.config
2. Sitecore.Commerce.ExperienceProfile.ReportingServer.config

To disable these files, simply append the `.disabled` extension after `.config`. The config processor will now ignore those files and they can be re-enabled if needed in the future.

Comment: I find this to be the proper resolution, unless more information can be provided by the Sitecore Support solution answer.